# The Next execution and last execution is N/A in Recurring Jobs - hangfire

Tags: c#, asp.net, hangfire

I have this code for Recurring Job and this is calling a BackgroundJob.Enqueue

`RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("indexes-scheduler", () => AppBuilderExtensions.checkIndexDate(), Cron.Minutely);`

and if I check dashboard after running the project the last execution and next execution shows N/A.

I tried to schedule a simple job

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("tests-job", () => Console.WriteLine("This job will execute once in every minute"), Cron.Minutely);
```

But still the same[image]

Comment: Could it be that time difference is simply to small to dispaly? Jobs can easily be done in millisecond. And this thing appears to be designed for tiems closer to seconds or minutes. Telling you the last job was 8 ms ago and the next one is due in 8ms will loose any value in the time it takes 16 ms to dliver that message to you.

Comment: I have tried increasing time interval too and also the calling method in recurring job never gets hit(have a breakpoint).

Answer (score 1):

Okay I got it working by using this script and also I tried to delete all servers from Hangfire.Server table

```
 TRUNCATE TABLE [HangFire].[AggregatedCounter]
 TRUNCATE TABLE [HangFire].[Counter]
 TRUNCATE TABLE [HangFire].[JobParameter]
 TRUNCATE TABLE [HangFire].[JobQueue]
 TRUNCATE TABLE [HangFire].[List]
 TRUNCATE TABLE [HangFire].[State]
 TRUNCATE TABLE [HangFire].[Server]
 DELETE FROM [HangFire].[Job]
 DBCC CHECKIDENT ('[HangFire].[Job]', reseed, 0)
 UPDATE [HangFire].[Hash] SET Value = 1 WHERE Field = 'LastJobId'
```

and eventually recreated those servers using this

```
app.UseHangfireServer();
```

This trick worked for me.